# Elastic Search Matching with a Filter

Tags: elasticsearch

New to elastic search and I need help with searching with a filter.  For example, I want to search for "Steven Spielberg" in `meta_values.meta_value` but only where `meta_value.meta_name = 'director'`, not where `meta_value.meta_name = 'producer'`, etc.  The query below will match "steven spielberg", but it also matches it when `meta_value.meta_name = 'producer'`.  I essentially want this filter to only search on directors.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_phrase": {
          "meta_values.meta_value": "steven spielberg"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "and": [{
          "term": {
            "meta_values.meta_name": "director"
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show one or two sample documents that are relevant to this issue? Also it would be nice to see what your current mapping is provided you're not using the dynamic/default one.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you experienced what is called *cross-object matching* in elasticsearch. The solution to that is `nested object`.

This concept has been explained really well in the book "Elasticsearch: The Definitive Guide". The pertinent chapter is [Nested Objects](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html) **<- click the link to read it and you don't have to read further**

Basically, if you have a doc like this:

```
{
  "name": "yj",
  "age": 30,
  "friends": [
    {
      "name": "jn",
      "age": 28
    },
    {
      "name": "abao",
      "age": 6
    }
  ]
}
```

Elasticsearch will flatten your document into:

```
{
  "name": "yj",
  "age": 30,
  "friends.name": ["jn", "abao"],
  "friends.age": [28, 6 ]
}
```

After the transformation, the relation between "jn" and `28` is lost. To avoid this, you can use `Nested object`, but you have to declare the field as `nested` type in the mapping upfront. Also almost anything involving the nested object will be cumbersome because in the query you have to explicitly say you are querying a nested field by declaring query as `nested` and also specify `path` to the property in the nested object.

The reason for the difference is that, `nested object` is a standalone document while the former example is stored as normal fields in the document after transformation.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of approach you can use the [Query String Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-dsl-query-string-query) feature in Elasticsearch,

so that you can frame your query as similar to as follows

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "(meta_values.meta_value:\"Steven Spielberg\" 
                    AND meta_value.meta_name: director) 
                    AND NOT meta_value.meta_name: producer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```